# Zend Framework module in command line

Tags: zend-framework, command-line, module, command-line-interface

I have Zend Framework command line application. All models and stuff that I use in this application are now in default module (Application prefix) but I want to move them to cli module. When I moved my model to application/cli/model folder and renamed class names then autoloader can't find them. I have also admin module and it is working fine.

Here is my server.php file:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../application'));
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
$application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap(array('date', 'config'));
```

and here is my application.ini:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

What should I do to make modules work in command line mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you're missing the bootstrap file for your Cli module - it should live at `application/modules/cli/Bootstrap.php`. You might also need to ensure the module and front controller resources are initialized by adding them to your array, giving you:

```
$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap(array('date', 'config', 'modules', 'frontController'));
```

If not we'll need more info, including the error you're getting, the class you are trying to use and where it is defined.

Comment: Yes, I know about Bootstrap.php file and it's there but it is a common mistake not to put it in new module directory. And you are a genius because adding 'modules', 'frontController' to bootstrap did the magic.

Comment: There is a problem. After moving all files to modules/cli/models/ directory and refactoring all classes I noticed that only one file is included corectly and only one class autoloaded. It is class which is called in server.php file. In this class there is other class called and this other class is not autoloading. It looks like autoloader is not looking into modules/cli/models/ directory because warning message shows include_path pointing to application/../library:.:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php. But it is working with class called in server.php.

Comment: The resource autoloader does not use the include path, so it is right that `modules/cli/models` does not appear there. You might need to post this as a new question, including details of the class you are trying to call, where it is defined (filename and file location), and your CLI module bootstrap.

Comment: While prepering new question I found out what I was doing wrong . It turn out that I made stupid typo while refactoring classes.

Answer (score 1):

WHat you need is a cli entry point.

Normally you enter the app on index.php (or /) in your browser aka via http. This will normally build a  response and a router. Because you are not comming via the web you have to tweak this a bit.

So create a file which you use as your entry point for example cli.php (copy it from public/index.php). And make some tweaks in it

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

// bootstrap and retrieve the frontController resource
$front = $application->getBootstrap()
                     ->bootstrap('frontController')
                     ->getResource('frontController');

//Which part of the app we want to use?
$module     = 'default'; //or other module
$controller = '<your controller>';
$action     = '<your action>';

//create the request
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Simple ($action, $controller, $module, $options);

// set front controller options to make everything operational from CLI
$front->setRequest($request)
      ->setResponse(new Zend_Controller_Response_Cli())
      ->setRouter(new Custom_Controller_Router_Cli())
      ->throwExceptions(true);

// lets bootstrap our application and enjoy!
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Comment: I changed my server.php file to match your sugestion but it didn't change anything. I still have the same error when trying to run it.